# The Peano form of the remainder of $\frac1{1+x^2}$'s Maclaurin formula?

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

I need to get the Maclaurin formula with the Peano form of the remainder of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Here is what I do:

Since we have $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2+...+(-1)^nx^n+o(x^n)$$
then $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4+...+(-1)^nx^{2n}+o(x^{2n})$$

But in my textbook the remainder is different:
$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4+...+(-1)^nx^{2n}+o(x^{2n+1})$$
I can't figure out why the remainder can be $o(x^{2n+1})$, which is stronger than $o(x^{2n})$. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: Since the function is even, it has implicit $+0\cdot x^{2n+1}$. Hence $o(x^{2n+1})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $$x \mapsto\frac1{1+x^2},\qquad x \in (-1,1),$$is *even*, then there is no term in $x^{2n+1}$ and you are allowed to write $o(x^{2n})=o(x^{2n+1})$.